# Vectorspaces and endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

let V be a K-vectorspace over the field K. Also let W be a vectorspace and W is isomoprh to V. Show that then End$_K(W)$ is an isomoprh ring to End$_K(V)$

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to define the map $\phi:End_K(V)\rightarrow End_K(W)$?

Comment: @QWERTZ actually i dont. Would you help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $V \cong W$, there exists an isomorphism $\phi:V \to W$.  Using this map, we construct the linear map
$$
\Phi: \operatorname{End}_K(V) \to \operatorname{End}_K(W)\\
[\Phi(f)](w) = \phi(f(\phi^{-1}(w)))
$$
That is, $\Phi(f) = \phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ for any $f \in \operatorname{End}_K(V)$.  Show that this map $\Phi$ is a ring homomorphism and that it is both injective and surjective.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic through a map, say $\psi:V\rightarrow W$. Given $\alpha\in End_K(V)$ you want to associate to it an element of $End_K(W)$, say $\phi(\alpha)$. A map is defined when it is known how it maps the elements of the domain, so to define $\phi(\alpha)$ you only need to say what it does on an element $w\in W$. You know how $\alpha$ is defined on $V$ and you know that $\psi^{-1}(w)$ is a well defined element of $V$, so $\alpha(\psi^{-1}(w))\in V$. If you apply again $\psi$ you get $\psi(\alpha(\psi^{-1}(w)))\in W$. Thus you can define $\phi(\alpha):=\psi\circ\alpha\circ\psi^{-1}$ (i.e. $(\phi(\alpha))(w)=(\psi\circ\alpha\circ\psi^{-1})(w),w\in W$) . Now you have to check that $\phi$ is actually a ring isomorphism and I leave this part to you (just check that it matches the definition of ring isomoprhism. To define the inverse $\phi^{-1}$ make the same argument I made to define $\phi$, only starting from an element of $End_{K}(W)$ instead of an element of $End_{K}(V)$).